# How to configure gradle rule base model plugin in gradle kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm using `play-application` plugin, which in turn use gradle rule based model configuration. `build.gradle.kts` looks like this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `play-application`
}

/* the snippet does not work
  model {
    components {
      play {
        platform play: playVersion, scala: scalaVersion, java: javaVersion
        injectedRoutesGenerator = true
      }
    }
  }
*/

// this works instead
apply(from = "play_setup.gradle")
val setup: groovy.lang.Closure<Any?> by extra
setup(project, jVersion, scalaVersion, playVersion)
```

where play_setup.gradle is:

```groovy
ext.setup = { project, javaVersion, scalaVersion, playVersion ->
  model {
    components {
      play {
        platform play: playVersion, scala: scalaVersion, java: javaVersion
        injectedRoutesGenerator = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to stop using groovy for plugins made with rule based model and configure them directly via kotlin-DSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not according to the [limitations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#kotdsl:limitations) listed in the Gradle Kotlin DSL Primer.

> The Kotlin DSL will not support the `model {}` block, which is part of
>   the [discontinued Gradle Software Model](https://blog.gradle.org/state-and-future-of-the-gradle-software-model). However, you can apply model
>   rules from scripts — see the [model rules sample](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/tree/master/samples/model-rules) for more information

The link to the model rules sample is broken in the documentation, but I fixed it above.